# How to use MenuItem as a NavLink?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom

I am trying to use a menu list to navigate through my application. Although, the app and routes are working fine i get some warnings in console using this piece of code :

```
{props.itemList.map((item, index) =>(
        <div key={index}>
          <MenuItem component={NavLink} to={item.to} onClick= 
              {handleClose} activeClassName={classes.topNavLinkActive} 
              className={classes.topNavLink}>
            {item.name}
            <Icon className={classes.navIcon}>{item.icon}</Icon>
          </MenuItem>
        </div>
      ))}
```

The warnings I get are :
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` supplied to `ForwardRef(ButtonBase)`. Expected an element type that can hold a ref. Did you accidentally provide a plain function component instead?

index.js:1375 Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Can someone please explain why forward referencing is required here?

Comment: Sir, were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the error is about misusing the `component` property. The docs say:

> The component used for the root node. Either a string to use a DOM element or a component.

According to [MenuItem API](https://material-ui.com/api/menu-item/#props), `component` property is of type `elementType`. The type definition file would show it's implementing `JSX.IntrinsicElements` interface (Which describe standard HTML tags).

`NavLink` element is a React component. Try providing a standard html tag name (`string`) or an actucal DOM node referance instead.